# Flask sessions not persisting on Google App Engine for a simple chess game

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine, session

I'm currently experiencing issues with Flask and sessions while developing a simple chess game. In this game, each time a new game starts, it is associated with a session. Everything works as expected when running the app locally. However, after deploying the app to Google App Engine, the current session gets removed after a few moves.

Here's some code to demonstrate how I configure the app and create a new session:

```py
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=".")
app.secret_key = "my_key"
CORS(app)

instances = {}

@app.route("/new-session")
def new_session():
    session_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    instances[session_id] = SomeClass(session_id)
    return {"session_id": session_id}
```

I'd prefer to avoid using Redis, as hosting it would incur additional costs. However, if that's the only viable solution, I'm open to exploring it. Any suggestions or alternative solutions to maintain session persistence on Google App Engine are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Storing session data in a cookie works fine with GAE.  You are not providing enough info for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: FYI: If you want to simulate production env locally (or something really close), make sure you run your App with ```dev_appserver.py``` and not invoke it directly with Flask/Python command